# Any recommendations for square/rectangle filter starter kit?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, neutral-density

**Context**

I've been using circular polarizes and related filters for my pictures using the screw in system. I've used the step up filter ring to fit larger filters on my smaller thread lens.

I'm debating on getting the square/rectangle filter systems for Soft-edge Gradient ND filter.

**Question**

I haven't use any system or know of any of them and I'm wondering if people have any recommendations for starting out?

I've seen the Lee filter system but I don't know if it is worth getting over other systems. I know that my largest thread is 77mm which is why I might get the 100mm system.

**Related**

[Screw-in or square filters in the field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19852)
[How do Cokin and Lee filter systems compare to each other?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/how-do-cokin-and-lee-filter-systems-compare-to-each-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee offers the 100mm system. Cokin offers similar systems in a larger variety of sizes. In your case with a maximum lens thread of 77mm, the Cokin "P" series that uses 84mm filters is a cheaper option to the Cokin Pro-Z series that uses 100mm filters. Because the filters are 84mm square instead of 100mm square, they only use about 70% as much glass and can thus be made at a lower cost.

Comment: I've seen that with Gradient ND filters, it's better to get it bigger so that I have "adjust" room if the horizon is too high or low. Will having only "7mm" make a difference versus the "23mm"?

Comment: Gradient filters are normally rectangular. The "P" series rectangular filters are 84x100mm. The Z-Pro and Lee gradient filters are 100x150mm. That gives you more room to slide them. But the same scale of proportion still holds: 84x100 is barely half the size of 100x150.

Comment: I also assume that larger filters be more fragile since it's more glass/resin but larger surface area? 
Looking on the [Cokin website](http://www.cokin.co.uk/pages/cokinP.htm) it seems that the only "limit" on 84x100mm is if I shoot really wide then?

Comment: Yes. With a FF camera 28mm and up with the standard "P" holder that can stack up to three filters, 20mm and up with the slim "P" holder that can only hold a single filter. Presumably with an APS-C camera you could go as wide as 19mm and 13mm respectively.